# fake returning visitor

Tags: security, visitors

I have a Live Support app installed on my website and I see a visitor every day, all day long for the last 3 months. This visitor has 3 or more IP addresses, but doesn't change them too often. It seems his (or her) browser supports Flash, and definietly supports JavaScript, because that's required for the Live Support app to collect data. Any idea what it might be, why would someone do such thing?

I tried to invite the visitor for chat, but my request was ignored. I also blocked two of his addresses, but he reappeared with a third one. He never visits any other page, just the one he landed on, usually our homepage.

Comment: @Rory Alsop I checked the last raw log file and he didn't do anything seemingly nasty on our server, but he only downloaded one HTML file (our main page), one favicon file and a few JS files, no CSS files or images or anything else, but that's probably because I encourage browsers to cache assets. He did download however two images when I sent him a Chat Request.

Answer (score 2):

They might have your website open on their browser on a tab they never look at, or looked at for a while but don't look at since.

Comment: I already blocked 2 of his primary ip addresses which he used to - solely - use for 2 months. after blocking them he came back the next day or the day after that.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are it is an automated tool, possibly going to your app through misconfiguration.

However it could be deliberate - you should get more info:

What activities take place while it is logged in? I would advise checking logs to see if it is trying to access anything, or if it is using your app to carry out activities either internal to your network or external.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over your html / javascript code ...

Create two fonctions, displayLiveHelp and hideLiveHelp
And add the following javascript

```
function onBlur() {
    hideLiveHelp();
};
function onFocus(){
    displayLiveHelp();
};

if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.onfocusin = onFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onBlur;
} else {
    window.onfocus = onFocus;
    window.onblur = onBlur;
}
```

Code inspiration:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active

Comment: or via window.addEventListener with the code here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720658/how-to-detect-when-a-tab-is-focused-or-not-in-chrome-with-javascript)